# Render script generated method: cannot find symbol method getPointSize()

Tags: java, android, renderscript, android-renderscript

Trying to load [3DLUT script](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/72226e0543461133b9e177a3e78ae50b0c65e797/tests/RenderScriptTests/ImageProcessing/src/com/android/rs/image/colorcube.rs) and [java code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/72226e0543461133b9e177a3e78ae50b0c65e797/tests/RenderScriptTests/ImageProcessing/src/com/android/rs/image/ImageProcessingActivity.java) from google, but the build failed with compiler generated file ScriptC_colorcube.java.

**Note** I've changed `int4` to `uint4` in line 60 through 66. Following is the error I recived while building it. The problematic line is at the firstline.

```
error: cannot find symbol method getPointerSize()
```

Generated code

```
    public void invoke_setCube(Allocation c) {
        FieldPacker setCube_fp = new FieldPacker((RenderScript.getPointerSize() == 8) ? 32 : 4);
        setCube_fp.addObj(c);
        invoke(mExportFuncIdx_setCube, setCube_fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be android gradle, after some investigation, I found there is some warning(`warning: Linking two modules of different data layouts: ...`) before the error.

I searched online and solved by removing `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true` in the gradle file.

I also changed all `android.support.v8.renderscript.*` to `android.renderscript.*`

Comment: Works for me, thanks. Could you please explain why do this ?

Comment: Hi, My understanding is that `android.support.v8...` and `android.renderscript.*` are different modules, and have different implementation, and `android.support.v8` provides better compatibility. Also I'm not sure why but the output of this method is different from 3rd party CPU only 3DLUT module, and cannot be explained with precision difference.